# Get Email from a people picker Field in MS Flow(Power Automate) - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, ms-flow

I have two lists in SharePoint Online, one to capture the data and another one where I have saved the value of approver in a people picker column.

Now I want the value of the people picker column in a variable so that I can set an approval action for them.

I have created a variable type object and I'm getting the below value in JSON format. I'm kind of new to Json hence I'm not aware how to get the email id from the json in MS FLOW.
Below is the json copied for ref.

```
{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser","Claims":"i:0#.f|membership|test@xx.com","DisplayName":"xx xx","Email":"xx.xx@xxxx.com","Picture":"https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxx/_layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName=xx.xx@xxxx.com","Department":null,"JobTitle":null}
```

Can some one please help me to get the email id value in a var from the above  JSON in MS FLow.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Person or Group** column:

1. In your flow add "Parse JSON" action found under Data Operation
2. For **Content** use the SharePoint field/column of type Person or Group (e.g. AssignedTo)
3. For **Schema** use the following.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "@@odata.type": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Claims": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "DisplayName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Email": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Picture": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Department": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "JobTitle": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

4. Now, for the subsequent actions such as **Grant access to an item**, you can use email  can be found under Parse JSON in the Dynamic Content

[image]